# Removing newlines when continuing a column on a new page

Tags: itext

I am using iTextSharp to generate a PDF on the fly. I am using the `ColumnText` class in **text mode** using the `ColumnText.SetColumns()` method to define column boundaries using code like the following:

```
myColumnText.SetColumns(leftCoords, rightCoords)

myColumnText.AddText(New Chunk("Lorem ipsum..."))
myColumnText.AddText(Chunk.NEWLINE))
myColumnText.AddText(Chunk.NEWLINE))
myColumnText.AddText(New Chunk("Lorem ipsum..."))
myColumnText.AddText(Chunk.NEWLINE))
myColumnText.AddText(Chunk.NEWLINE))
```

As you can see, I emit a block of text and then two `Chunk.NEWLINE`s to add whitespace between paragraphs.

I then use `ColumnText.Go` to emit the content, creating new pages as needed, like so:

```
While ColumnText.HasMoreText(myColumnText.Go())
    myDocument.NewPage()

    myColumnText.SetColumns(leftCoords, rightCoords)
End While
```

The problem I am running into is that depending on the content in the `ColumnText` object a page break might occur right at the end of a chunk of text but before the `Chunk.NEWLINE`s, meaning that the content on the next page starts with two `Chunk.NEWLINE`s rather than at the top of the page.

Is there a way to somehow suppress `Chunk.NEWLINE`s if they are the first things emitted on a new page? My thought was that if I could somehow see the text that was about to be emitted by `ColumnText.Go` I could see if I was about to emit a `Chunk.NEWLINE` and remove it from the content stream or something...

Thanks

Comment: Normally, you wouldn't use newlines to achieve what you want, but `setSpacingAfter()` ( http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Paragraph.html#setSpacingAfter(float) )

Comment: @BrunoLowagie, `setSpacingAfter()` is for the `Paragraph`, I'm adding `Chunk`s. Also, would `setSpacingAfter()` work as advertised even though I am in **text mode**?

Comment: Good catch, it wouldn't work in text mode. Your requirement is interesting, but it requires core iText development.